# How to store the current value of a macro?

Tags: macros

I defined a macro `\test` as follows:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\temp]
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\temp\endcsname{Name: \temp}
}
```

It creates a new macro with the name of its parameter, and then store this name inside this new macro (I only create this macro to illustrate my question, not that I really need the functionality of this macro). Thus, with

```
\test{aaa}
\aaa
```

one would get `Name: aaa`. However, if there's a `\test{bbb}` after this, then `\aaa` becomes `Name: bbb`, since `\aaa` stores the macro`\temp`, not its value.

I wish to keep the value of `aaa` a constant. For this I tried to add `\expandafter` before `\temp`, but it didn't work. What is the proper way to do this?

(I know I can change the second `\newcommand` in this example to `\edef` to solve this. But this won't work if I'm using `\newtheorem`. What I really wish to know is how to get the **value** of `\temp`.)

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{0}[\temp]
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\temp\endcsname{Name: \temp}
}

\begin{document}

\test{aaa}
\aaa

\test{bbb}
\aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to do `\newtheorem`, why not simply doing `\newcommand{\test}[1]{\newtheorem{#1}{Name: #1}}`?

Comment: @egreg Actually I am writing a class file, in which I need to detect if a string contains `*` at last and remove the `*` if it does. The resulted string is `\temp`, and is used in many places. It is a little bit hard for me do make a real MWE.

Comment: Then ask the real question with some more details.

Comment: @egreg See the description under [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586197/194994).

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? I was just about to post an answer that should've covered everything... :(

Comment: @Skillmon I'm writing a new one that mainly focus on the macro `\CreateTheorem`. Previously I'm asking things related to it, but was hard to read and to answer.

Comment: @Skillmon Please have a look at the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586211/194994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\edef` instead `\def`:

```
\def\test#1{%
   \def\temp{#1}% It emulates your \StrGobble
   \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{Name: \temp}
}
```

Or more straightforward:

```
\def\test#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{Name: #1}}
```

**Edit** Ok, when you are using `\newtheorem` then you have more work. (I never use such things as `\newcommand` or `\newtheorem`, only `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef`, `\xdef`, so, my life with TeX is more simple).

You can use `\edef\tempi` and three `\expandafter`s:

```
\def\test#1{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \edef\tempi{name: \temp}%
    \expandafter\newtheorem\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\tempi}%
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this, and I've stated it in my question. Perhaps I haven't chosen the proper example. Actually I'm using `\temp` inside a `\newtheorem`, and `\edef` doesn't seem very helpful in this case.

Comment: I just edited my question to use `\newtheorem` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Jinwen OK, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for this! May I ask what are these `\expandafter` for in `\expandafter\newtheorem\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\tempi}`? I have no idea when or where should I add it.

Comment: You need to process `\newtheorem{\temp}{expanded\tempi}`, so you must to expand the `\tempi` by `\expandafter`. The `\expandafter`s chain must skip all tokens which need not to be expanded before `\newtheorem` is processed. Moreower, `\newtheorem` accepts its first parameter as one token `\temp`, you need not use three tokens `{\temp}` here. So, you can spare two `\expandafter`s in the chain.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `xstring`, but it's much simpler with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{O{0}m}
 {
  \jinwen_test:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jinwen_test:nn
 {% #1 = how many characters to gobble from the right
  % #2 = string
  \cs_new:cpx { #2 } { Name: ~ \tl_range:nnn { #2 } { 1 } { - 1 - #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\frenchspacing 

\begin{document}

\test{aaa}
\test[3]{abcdef}

\texttt{\meaning\aaa}

\texttt{\meaning\abcdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xstring` you can use an argument swapping technique in order to avoid `\edef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[2][0]{%
  \StrGobbleRight{#2}{#1}[\jinwen@temp]
  \expandafter\jinwen@makecommand\expandafter{\jinwen@temp}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\jinwen@makecommand}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#2\endcsname{Name: #1}%
}
\makeatother

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\test{aaa}
\test[3]{abcdef}

\texttt{\meaning\aaa}

\texttt{\meaning\abcdef}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I don't know how to fix my new added example in the question (the one with `\newtheorem`) according to your answer. Would you mind looking into it?

Comment: @Jinwen You should never change a question so as to invalidate existing answers. Of course the answer to the modified question is just to do `\newtheorem{#1}{Name #1}`. Please, roll back. And you should ***never*** do `\newtheorem{aaa}{...}` and use `\aaa\endaaa`.

Answer (score 2):

Approaches where a temporary macro `\temp` is defined by `\StrGobbleRight` only work out as long as the string in question does not contain hashes (`#`).

---

You can have the toplevel-expansion of `\temp` as an argument of another macro which does the actual work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\temp]%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\innertest\expandafter{\temp}%
}%
\newcommand\innertest[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{Name: #1}%
}%


\begin{document}

\test{aaax}

\test{bbbx}

\texttt{\string\aaa:\meaning\aaa}

\texttt{\string\bbb:\meaning\bbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If ε-TeX-extensions are allowed you can use `\protected@edef` and wrap everything but `\temp` into `\unexpanded`—actually in this example `\unexpanded` is not needed as the characters `Name:`  are not expandable, but there might be something like `\newtheorem` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\temp]%
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname\temp\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\protected@edef\csname\temp\endcsname{\unexpanded{Name: }\temp}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{aaax}

\test{bbbx}

\texttt{\string\aaa:\meaning\aaa}

\texttt{\string\bbb:\meaning\bbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you like it complicated you can apply `\expandafter` before `\Exchange`ing  tokens.
You can use `\romannumeral` for keeping expansion going until a non-positive number is found.
(`\romannumeral` silently discards non-positive numbers without delivering any token in return.)

With the example below `\Stopromannumeral` denotes the number `0` in a way where you don't have unwanted removal of a trailing space token and where no explicit character-token `0` is involved which could probably be affected/changed by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`.

The `\expandafter`-chain launched during the expansion of `\csname` launches `\romannumeral`-expansion.
`\romannumeral` in turn triggers expanding the two `\expandafter` behind the `\romannumeral`-token which in turn yields toplevel-expansion of `\temp`.
Then `\romannumeral` triggers `\Exchange`.
After that `\Stopromannumeral`, i.e., a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity of value "0", is found which ends `\romannumeral` with `\romannumeral` discarding the tokens forming that *⟨number⟩*-quantity without delivering tokens in return.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\Stopromannumeral{\chardef\Stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\makeatother


\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\temp]%
    \expandafter\newcommand
    \csname\temp\expandafter\endcsname
                \expandafter{%
                  \romannumeral
                  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\temp}{\Stopromannumeral Name: }%
                }%
}%


\begin{document}

\test{aaax}

\test{bbbx}

\texttt{\string\aaa:\meaning\aaa}

\texttt{\string\bbb:\meaning\bbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]