# Help on a macro \CreateTheorem(*)

Tags: macros, theorems, babel, cleveref

I'm trying to define a macro `\CreateTheorem(*)`, the intention is to be able to define the theorem-like environments as easy as before, but can be traced correctly by `cref` in a multi-language document. For example,

```
\CreateTheorem{theorem}<section>
\CreateTheorem{definition}[theorem]
```

should create `theorem` and `definition` environments as usual. The result would be like (this is produced by the document in the last of this question, which manually does the work of `\CreateTheorem`):

[image: result]

Currently I have (below is a complete, but not yet working MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{simple}%
    {}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {0pt}%
    {\thmname{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\thmnumber{ #2}\hspace{.4em}\textcolor{gray!55!paper}{$|$}\hspace{.4em}\color{gray}\thmnote{\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}~~}\pushQED{\qed}}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\makebox[1em]{\color{gray!55!paper}\rule[-0.1em]{.95em}{.95em}}}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,linktoc=all}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nameinlink}{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3~\aftergroup\ignorespaces}

\theoremstyle{simple}

\newcommand\englishABBR{EN}
\newcommand\frenchABBR{FR}

%% macro for creating theorems
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateTheorem}{smod<>}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% Stared version
        \IfEndWith{#2}{*}
        {% \CreateTheorem*{theorem*}
            \StrGobbleRight{#2}{1}[\temp]%
            \newtheorem*{\temp EN*}{\csname\temp nameEN\endcsname}
            \newtheorem*{\temp FR*}{\csname\temp nameFR\endcsname}
            \NewDocumentEnvironment{\temp*}{O{}}{\begin{\temp \csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[##1]}{\end{\temp \csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
        }
        {% \CreateTheorem*{theorem}
            \newtheorem*{#2EN}{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}
            \newtheorem*{#2FR}{\csname#2nameFR\endcsname}
            \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{O{}}{\begin{#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[##1]}{\end{#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
        }%
    }
    {% Non-stared version
        \IfEndWith{#2}{*}
        {% \CreateTheorem{theorem*}[...]<...>
            \StrGobbleRight{#2}{1}[\temp]%
            \newtheorem{\temp EN*}[#3]{\csname\temp nameEN\endcsname}[#4]
            \newtheorem{\temp FR*}[#3]{\csname\temp nameFR\endcsname}[#4]
            \crefname{\temp EN*}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname\temp nameEN\endcsname}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname\temp nameEN\endcsname}}
            \crefname{\temp FR*}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname\temp nameFR\endcsname}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname\temp nameFR\endcsname}}
            \NewDocumentEnvironment{\temp*}{O{}}{\begin{\temp \csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[##1]}{\end{\temp \csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
        }
        {% \CreateTheorem{theorem}[...]<...>
            \newtheorem{#2EN}[#3]{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}[#4]
            \newtheorem{#2FR}[#3]{\csname#2nameFR\endcsname}[#4]
            \crefname{#2EN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}}
            \crefname{#2FR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname#2nameFR\endcsname}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname#2nameFR\endcsname}}
            \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{O{}}{\begin{#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[##1]}{\end{#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
        }%
    }%
}

\def\theoremnameEN{Theorem}
\def\theoremnameFR{Théorème}
\def\definitionnameEN{Definition}
\def\definitionnameFR{Définition}
\def\remarknameEN{Remark}
\def\remarknameFR{Remarque}
\def\notenameEN{Note}
\def\notenameFR{Note}

\CreateTheorem{theorem}<section>
\CreateTheorem{definition}[theorem]
\CreateTheorem*{theorem*}
\CreateTheorem*{definition*}
\CreateTheorem*{remark}
\CreateTheorem{note*} % This is strange, only for test

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

There're two problems:

1. As @Skillmon points out to me, one cannot use `\newtheorem` with two counters as optional arguments. ([Using \newtheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/using-newtheorem)) So `[#3]` and `[#4]` should only appear when they are non-empty.
2. The `theorem*` case uses `\temp` string, which is not static and may get changed. Something similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586182/how-to-store-the-current-value-of-a-macro) should be considered.

Could anyone please help me building this macro?

---

*This macro is intended to simplify to process for defining theorem-like environments in a multi-language document. Below is a document with manually defined theorem-like environments. As a comparison, when `\CreateTheorem` is finished, it should be able to produce the same result, but with a much easier process.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{simple}%
    {}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {0pt}%
    {\thmname{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\thmnumber{ #2}\hspace{.4em}\textcolor{gray!55!paper}{$|$}\hspace{.4em}\color{gray}\thmnote{\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}~~}\pushQED{\qed}}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\makebox[1em]{\color{gray!55!paper}\rule[-0.1em]{.95em}{.95em}}}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,linktoc=all}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nameinlink}{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3~\aftergroup\ignorespaces}

\theoremstyle{simple}

\newcounter{theorem}
\newcounter{conjecture}
\newcounter{example}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{remark}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{conjecture}{section}
\numberwithin{example}{section}
\numberwithin{problem}{section}
\numberwithin{remark}{section}

\newcommand\englishABBR{EN}
\newcommand\frenchABBR{FR}

%% English theorems
\newtheorem{theoremEN}[theorem]{\theoremnameEN}
\newtheorem{lemmaEN}[theorem]{\lemmanameEN}
\newtheorem{propositionEN}[theorem]{\propositionnameEN}
\newtheorem{corollaryEN}[theorem]{\corollarynameEN}
\newtheorem{factEN}[theorem]{\factnameEN}
\newtheorem{conjectureEN}[conjecture]{\conjecturenameEN}
\newtheorem*{theoremEN*}{\theoremnameEN}
\newtheorem*{lemmaEN*}{\lemmanameEN}
\newtheorem*{propositionEN*}{\propositionnameEN}
\newtheorem*{corollaryEN*}{\corollarynameEN}
\newtheorem*{factEN*}{\factnameEN}
\newtheorem*{conjectureEN*}{\conjecturenameEN}
\newtheorem{definitionEN}[theorem]{\definitionnameEN}
\newtheorem{exampleEN}[example]{\examplenameEN}
\newtheorem{problemEN}[problem]{\problemnameEN}
\newtheorem*{definitionEN*}{\definitionnameEN}
\newtheorem*{exampleEN*}{\examplenameEN}
\newtheorem*{problemEN*}{\problemnameEN}
\newtheorem{remarkEN}[remark]{\remarknameEN}
\newtheorem*{remarkEN*}{\remarknameEN}


\def\theoremnameEN{Theorem}
\def\lemmanameEN{Lemma}
\def\propositionnameEN{Proposition}
\def\corollarynameEN{Corollary}
\def\factnameEN{Fact}
\def\conjecturenameEN{Conjecture}
\def\definitionnameEN{Definition}
\def\examplenameEN{Example}
\def\problemnameEN{Problem}
\def\remarknameEN{Remark}

%% French theorems
\newtheorem{theoremFR}[theorem]{\theoremnameFR}
\newtheorem{lemmaFR}[theorem]{\lemmanameFR}
\newtheorem{propositionFR}[theorem]{\propositionnameFR}
\newtheorem{corollaryFR}[theorem]{\corollarynameFR}
\newtheorem{factFR}[theorem]{\factnameFR}
\newtheorem{conjectureFR}[conjecture]{\conjecturenameFR}
\newtheorem*{theoremFR*}{\theoremnameFR}
\newtheorem*{lemmaFR*}{\lemmanameFR}
\newtheorem*{propositionFR*}{\propositionnameFR}
\newtheorem*{corollaryFR*}{\corollarynameFR}
\newtheorem*{factFR*}{\factnameFR}
\newtheorem*{conjectureFR*}{\conjecturenameFR}
\newtheorem{definitionFR}[theorem]{\definitionnameFR}
\newtheorem{exampleFR}[example]{\examplenameFR}
\newtheorem{problemFR}[problem]{\problemnameFR}
\newtheorem*{definitionFR*}{\definitionnameFR}
\newtheorem*{exampleFR*}{\examplenameFR}
\newtheorem*{problemFR*}{\problemnameFR}
\newtheorem{remarkFR}[remark]{\remarknameFR}
\newtheorem*{remarkFR*}{\remarknameFR}

\def\theoremnameFR{Théorème}
\def\lemmanameFR{Lemme}
\def\propositionnameFR{Proposition}
\def\corollarynameFR{Corollaire}
\def\factnameFR{Fait}
\def\conjecturenameFR{Conjecture}
\def\definitionnameFR{Définition}
\def\examplenameFR{Exemple}
\def\problemnameFR{Problème}
\def\remarknameFR{Remarque}

%% cleveref configuration
\crefname{theoremEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\theoremnameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\theoremnameEN}}
\crefname{lemmaEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\lemmanameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\lemmanameEN}}
\crefname{propositionEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\propositionnameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\propositionnameEN}}
\crefname{corollaryEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\corollarynameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\corollarynameEN}}
\crefname{factEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\factnameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\factnameEN}}
\crefname{conjectureEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\conjecturenameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\conjecturenameEN}}
\crefname{definitionEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\definitionnameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\definitionnameEN}}
\crefname{exampleEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\examplenameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\examplenameEN}}
\crefname{problemEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\problemnameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\problemnameEN}}
\crefname{remarkEN}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\remarknameEN}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\remarknameEN}}

\crefname{theoremFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\theoremnameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\theoremnameFR}}
\crefname{lemmaFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\lemmanameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\lemmanameFR}}
\crefname{propositionFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\propositionnameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\propositionnameFR}}
\crefname{corollaryFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\corollarynameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\corollarynameFR}}
\crefname{factFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\factnameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\factnameFR}}
\crefname{conjectureFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\conjecturenameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\conjecturenameFR}}
\crefname{definitionFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\definitionnameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\definitionnameFR}}
\crefname{exampleFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\examplenameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\examplenameFR}}
\crefname{problemFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\problemnameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\problemnameFR}}
\crefname{remarkFR}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\remarknameFR}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{\remarknameFR}}

%% Theorem environments
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}}{\begin{theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem*}{O{}}{\begin{theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{theorem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{lemma}{O{}}{\begin{lemma\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{lemma\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{lemma*}{O{}}{\begin{lemma\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{lemma\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{proposition}{O{}}{\begin{proposition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{proposition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{proposition*}{O{}}{\begin{proposition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{proposition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{corollary}{O{}}{\begin{corollary\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{corollary\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{corollary*}{O{}}{\begin{corollary\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{corollary\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fact}{O{}}{\begin{fact\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{fact\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fact*}{O{}}{\begin{fact\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{fact\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{conjecture}{O{}}{\begin{conjecture\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{conjecture\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{conjecture*}{O{}}{\begin{conjecture\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{conjecture\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{O{}}{\begin{definition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{definition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition*}{O{}}{\begin{definition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{definition\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{O{}}{\begin{example\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{example\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example*}{O{}}{\begin{example\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{example\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problem}{O{}}{\begin{problem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{problem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problem*}{O{}}{\begin{problem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{problem\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{remark}{O{}}{\begin{remark\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}[#1]}{\end{remark\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{remark*}{O{}}{\begin{remark\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}[#1]}{\end{remark\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname*}}


\def\sometext{Here's some text without a meaning. This text ...}

\begin{document}

In English:

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}
    \sometext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
    \sometext
\end{theorem*}

\begin{definition}\label{def:1}
    \sometext
\end{definition}

\selectlanguage{french}

En français:

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:2}
    \sometext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
    \sometext
\end{theorem*}

\begin{definition}\label{def:2}
    \sometext
\end{definition}

\selectlanguage{english}

See \cref{thm:1,thm:2,def:1,def:2}. % reference should be in their original language

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the difference between `\CreateTheorem*{foo}`, `\CreateTheorem*{foo}` and `\CreateTheorem*{foo*}` should be.

Comment: @egreg `\CreateTheorem` creates numbered theorems, `\CreateTheorem*` creates unnumbered theorems. `foo` and `foo*` are just different choices of names, I chose to process them separately because I want `fooEN*`, not `foo*EN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish cleveref to work I suggest defining a counter `⟨name of environment⟩` and using the package [aliascnt](https://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt) for defining alias-counters  `⟨name of environment⟩EN` and `⟨name of environment⟩FR`.
(Splitting a trailing `*` from the `⟨name of environment⟩` is taken into account with the example below.)
Then you can define new theorems via
`\newtheorem{⟨name of environment⟩EN}[⟨name of environment⟩EN]{⟨header⟩}`
respective
`\newtheorem{⟨name of environment⟩FR}[⟨name of environment⟩FR]{⟨header⟩}`
and you run into problems

- neither with cleveref or hyperref's `\autoref` choosing the right `\..name`-macro
- nor with `\newtheorem`-directives where the counter to use is not specified with a trailing `EN`/`FR`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- needed for French language !!!

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{simple}%
    {}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {0pt}%
    {\thmname{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\thmnumber{ #2}\hspace{.4em}\textcolor{gray!55!paper}{$|$}\hspace{.4em}\color{gray}\thmnote{\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}~~}\pushQED{\qed}}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\makebox[1em]{\color{gray!55!paper}\rule[-0.1em]{.95em}{.95em}}}

\RequirePackage{aliascnt}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,linktoc=all}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nameinlink}{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3~\aftergroup\ignorespaces}

\theoremstyle{simple}

\newcommand\englishABBR{EN}
\newcommand\frenchABBR{FR}

%% macro for creating theorems
\RequirePackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateTheorem}{sm}{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\temp{#2}%
  \expandafter\IfEndWith\expandafter{\temp}{*}{%
    \expandafter\StrGobbleRight\expandafter{\temp}{1}[\temp]%
    \PassFirstToSecond{*}%
  }{%
    \PassFirstToSecond{}%
  }%
  {\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\temp}{\endgroup\InnerCreateTheorem{#1}}}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\InnerCreateTheorem}{mmmod<>}{%
   % #1 = Tokens denoting an xparse-boolean value;
   %      value "true" -> the call was \CreateTheorem*{...}...
   %      value "false" -> the call was \CreateTheorem{...}...
   %      This indicates whether the "starred" variant or the
   %      "unstarred" variant of \CreateTheorem was called.
   % #2 = Name of environment to define. One trailing
   %      star is removed from the environment-name provided 
   %      to \CreateTheorem if that environment-name has
   %      trailing stars.
   % #3 = If the environment-name provided to \CreateTheorem has
   %      trailing stars: A star (*).
   %      If the environment-name provided to \CreateTheorem has
   %      no trailing stars: Empty/no tokens at all.
   % #4 = numbered like=name of counter like which the environment
   %      shall be numbered.
   % #5 = numbered within=name of counter which is superordinate
   %      to the environment's counter and whose stepping resets
   %      the environment's counter.
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
     \IfValueTF{#4}{\@firstoftwo}{\IfValueTF{#5}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}}%
   }{\IfValueTF{#4}{\IfValueTF{#5}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}}{\@secondoftwo}}%
   {%
    \GenericError{}%
                 {\string\CreateTheorem\space syntax error\on@line}%
                 {You cannot call the starred variant with optional arguments.\MessageBreak
                  You cannot call the unstarred variant with several optional arguments.}%
                 {%
                   Allowed usage:\MessageBreak\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem*{(name of environment)}\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}[(numbered like)]\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}<(numbered within)>\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}\MessageBreak
                   Captions come from macros \string\(name of environment)nameEN\MessageBreak
                   respective \string\(name of environment)nameFR.\MessageBreak
                   These macros must be defined separately.%
                 }%
   }{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}{\newtheorem*{#2EN#3}}%
        \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\csname#2nameFR\endcsname}{\newtheorem*{#2FR#3}}%
      }{%
        \IfValueTF{#5}{%
          \newcounter{#2#3}[{#5}]%
          \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter*\csname the#2#3\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\csname the#5\endcsname.\arabic{#2#3}}%
        }{%
          \IfValueTF{#4}{\newaliascnt{#2#3}{#4}}{\newcounter{#2#3}}%
        }%
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \CreateTheoremNumberedLikeAliasCounter{#2}{EN}{#3}%
        \CreateTheoremNumberedLikeAliasCounter{#2}{FR}{#3}%
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }%
      \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2#3}{}{\csname#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#3\endcsname}%
                                     {\csname end#2\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#3\endcsname}%
   }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateTheoremNumberedLikeAliasCounter}{mmm}{%
  \newaliascnt{#1#2#3}{#1#3}%
  \newtheorem{#1#2#3}[{#1#2#3}]{\csname#1name#2\endcsname}%
  \aliascntresetthe{#1#2#3}%
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\expandafter\protect\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\csname#1name#2\endcsname}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\expandafter\protect\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\csname#1name#2\endcsname}}%
    {\crefname{#1#2#3}}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\def\theoremnameEN{Theorem}
\def\theoremnameFR{Théorème}
\def\definitionnameEN{Definition}
\def\definitionnameFR{Définition}
\def\remarknameEN{Remark}
\def\remarknameFR{Remarque}
\def\notenameEN{Note}
\def\notenameFR{Note}

\CreateTheorem{theorem}<section>
\CreateTheorem{definition}[theorem]
\CreateTheorem*{theorem*}
\CreateTheorem*{definition*}
\CreateTheorem*{remark}
\CreateTheorem{note*} % This is strange, only for test

\newcommand*\sometext{Here's some text without a meaning. This text ...}

\begin{document}

In English:

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}%
    \sometext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
    \sometext
\end{theorem*}

\begin{definition}\label{def:1}%
    \sometext
\end{definition}

\selectlanguage{french}

En français:

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:2}%
    \sometext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
    \sometext
\end{theorem*}

\begin{definition}\label{def:2}%
    \sometext
\end{definition}

\selectlanguage{english}

See \cref{thm:1,thm:2,def:1,def:2}. % reference should be in their original language

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Is the use of `\PassFirstToSecond` just to make the code look clearer, or is it because that it has some real propose? 2) How do `\@firstoftwo`, `\@secondoftwo` and `\GenericError` work here? That is, to whom `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` are pointing to?

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really helpful to me.

Comment: @Jinwen You are welcome. :-)  When I started learning LaTeX the learning curve was rather steep because the programming-paradigm differs from that of programming-languages like Pascal or C or C++. If you have questions about how things work in TeX/in code of mine, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Jinwen Ad 1:Think of `\PassFirstToSecond` as `\PassFirstToSecond{<Argument-Tokens>}{<Argument-Processing-Tokens>}` yielding `<Argument-Processing-Tokens>{<Argument-Tokens>}`. You can have TeX **beforehand** modify/change the `<Argument-Tokens>` by going at the `<Argument-Tokens>` via `\expandafter` or `\romannumeral` or some other expansion-trickery. Hereby you don't need to have TeX jump over an unknown amount of tokens but to jump over `\PassFirstToSecond` and `{` only. You can even use some forking for choosing which tokens to place behind `<Argument-Processing-Tokens>`. So there is a ...

Comment: @Jinwen Ad 1: ... So there is a real purpose: Control the order of processing things and passing the results as arguments to other tokens during the stage of expansion

Comment: @Jinwen Ad 2: At the top of the definition of `\InnerCreateTheorem` you find a bunch of nested `\IfBooleanTF-` and `\IfValueTF`-directives which in the end either deliver `\@firstoftwo` or deliver `\@secondoftwo`. Behind that you find two macro-arguments which each holds a lot of tokens. These directives detect if star/optional arguments are provided in a combination not permitted with `\newtheorem`. If so, then `\@firstoftwo` is carried out which yields delivering the first argument without the surrounding curly braces and just removing the second argument. ...

Comment: @Jinwen Ad 2: ... the second argument. The first argument holds the `\GenericError`-command which delivers the error-message. If not so, `\@secondoftwo` is carried out which yields just removing the first argument and delivering the second argument without the surrounding curly braces. The second argument holds the tokens to carry out in order to create the new theorem-environments.

Comment: @Jinwen Ad 1: I often prefer `\@firstoftwo`/`\@secondoftwo` to `\if<condition><A bunch of tokens>\else<Another bunch of tokens>\fi` because with `\@firstoftwo`/`\@secondoftwo` tokens not carried out are removed from memory immediately instead of being accumulated until either being removed in some later stage of processing/expansion or causing TeX-capacity-exceeded-error-messages.

Comment: @Jinwen In situations where forking/branching takes place `\PassFirstToSecond` is also a means of avoiding writing the same bunch of tokens twice. E.g, the first usage of `\PassFirstToSecond` within `\CreateTheorem` is such a thing: The `\IfEndWith`-fork selects, by choosing the appropriate `\PassFirstToSecond`-command,  what to place behind the tokens `\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\temp}{\endgroup\InnerCreateTheorem{#1}}`  without the need of writing all these tokens twice. ;-) You either have `{*}` or `{}` behind them, denoting what to append to names of internal environments.

Comment: I changed the lines with `\PassFirstToSecond` in `\InnerCreateTheorem` to `\newtheorem*{#2EN#3}{\csname#2nameEN\endcsname}`, and those in `\CreateTheoremNumberedLikeAliasCounter` to `\crefname{#1#2#3}{\textsc{\csname#1name#2\endcsname}}{\textsc{\csname#1name#2\endcsname}}`. Is this safe? I mean, it seems those parameters passed to these two macros have already been expanded by the main macro `\CreateTheorem`, so I needn't to expand them again, is this right?

Comment: @Jinwen You can do this and it will work out. But: Then the `\csname..\endcsname`-constructs are not evaluated only once, namely at the time of defining the theorem-environments but they get evaluated each time the environments are used. This way TeX has more work to do and needs more memory for storing the macro-definitions underlying the begin- and end-macros of the environments to define as these definitions will not consist of the single control-word-token formed from the evaluation of `\csname..\endcsname` but will consist of all tokens forming the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression.

Comment: I recently adopted your method into a package, but (the fault is on me) the code is quite time-consuming, so I posted a question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596657/194994. Perhaps you would have some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I believe your approach is not the best one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\newtheoremstyle{simple}%
  {}
  {}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
   \thmname{#1}%
   \thmnumber{ #2}%
   \hspace{.4em}%
   \textcolor{gray!55!paper}{$|$}%
   \hspace{.4em}\color{gray}%
   \thmnote{(#3)~~}\pushQED{\qed}%
  }
\makeatletter
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{simple}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateTheorem}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \jinwen_theorem_nonumber:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \jinwen_theorem_number:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { jinwen/theorem }
 {
  within .tl_set:N = \l__jinwen_theorem_within_tl,
  like .tl_set:N = \l__jinwen_theorem_like_tl,
  name .tl_set:N = \l__jinwen_theorem_name_tl,
  unknown .code:n = 
   \prop_gput:cVn { g_jinwen_theorem_ \l__jinwen_theorem_main_tl _prop }
                  \l_keys_key_str { #1 },
 }
\tl_new:N \l__jinwen_theorem_main_tl
\str_new:N \l_jinwen_language_curr_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jinwen_theorem_nonumber:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__jinwen_theorem_main_tl { #1 }
  \prop_new:c { g_jinwen_theorem_#1_prop }
  \keys_set:nn { jinwen/theorem }
   {
    #2, % set the given options
   }
  \newtheorem*{#1}{ \__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jinwen_theorem_number:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__jinwen_theorem_main_tl { #1 }
  \prop_new:c { g_jinwen_theorem_#1_prop }
  \keys_set:nn { jinwen/theorem }
   {
    within = , % initialize to empty
    like =, % initialize to empty
    #2, % set the given options
   }
  \jinwen_theorem_new:nVV { #1 } \l__jinwen_theorem_within_tl \l__jinwen_theorem_like_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \jinwen_theorem_new:nnn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
   {% no within
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 }
     {% no like
      \newtheorem{#1}{ \__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }
     }
     {% numbered like
      \newtheorem{#1}[#3]{ \__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }
     }
   }
   {% within
    \newtheorem{#1}{ \__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }[#2]
   }
  \crefname{#1}{ \protect\__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }
               { \protect\__jinwen_theorem_printname:n { #1 } }

 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jinwen_theorem_new:nnn { nVV }

\cs_new:Nn \__jinwen_theorem_printname:n
 {
  \text_uppercase:n { \prop_item:cV { g_jinwen_theorem_#1_prop } \l_jinwen_language_curr_str }
 }

\addto\captionsenglish{\tl_set:Nn \l_jinwen_language_curr_str { EN } }
\addto\captionsfrench{\tl_set:Nn \l_jinwen_language_curr_str { FR } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\CreateTheorem{theorem}{within=section,EN=Theorem,FR=Théorème}
\CreateTheorem{lemma}{EN=Lemma,FR=Lemme}
\CreateTheorem*{foo}{EN=abc,FR=xyz}

\CreateTheorem{theorem*}{like=theorem,EN=Easy Theorem,FR=Théorème facile}
\CreateTheorem*{foo*}{EN=foo,FR=xyz}

\begin{document}

\section{English}

\begin{lemma}\label{l}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}
\cref{l}

\begin{theorem}\label{a}
This is in English.
\end{theorem}
\cref{a}

\begin{theorem*}[Very easy]\label{b}
This is in English.
\end{theorem*}
\cref{b}

\begin{foo}
This is in English and is named abc.
\end{foo}

\begin{foo*}
This is in English and is named abc.
\end{foo*}

\selectlanguage{french}

\section{Français}

\begin{lemma}\label{m}
Ceci est un lemme.
\end{lemma}
\cref{m}

\begin{theorem}\label{c}
Ceci est en français.
\end{theorem}
\cref{c}

\begin{theorem*}[Très facile]\label{d}
Ceci est en français.
\end{theorem*}
\cref{d}

\begin{foo}
Ceci est en français et est nommé xyz.
\end{foo}

\begin{foo*}
Ceci est en français et est nommé xyz.
\end{foo*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there is too much uppercasing going on, but it's your document, not mine.

Answer (score 2):

The following solves your `\temp` expansion issue by using two helper macros, one for the starred one for the unstarred case. The one in the unstarred case makes sure that only the correct optional arguments are forwarded, and throws an error if both were used.

You don't need `\edef`, this answer just expands your `\temp` macro using `\expandafter`. The general rule for `\expandafter` is that `\expandafter<tokA><tokB>` tries to expand `<tokB>` before `<tokA>` is expanded, so `\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\stuff}` will do the following (this lists four steps, but you can't really access these steps, TeX will do all these steps when it expands the first `\expandafter` once):

1. `\expandafter` defers `\foo`:

   ```
   % to be reinserted
   \expandafter\foo
   % next things TeX will look at
   \expandafter{\stuff}
   ```
2. the second `\expandafter` defers `{`:

   ```
   % to be reinserted
   \expandafter\foo\expandafter{%
   % next things TeX will look at
   \stuff}
   ```
3. `\stuff` gets expanded and the deferred `\expandafter{` gets put back (with `\expandafter` getting removed, `<stuff>` being the expansion of `\stuff`)

   ```
   % to be reinserted
   \expandafter\foo
   % next things TeX will look at
   {<stuff>}
   ```
4. and finally `\expandafter\foo` gets reinserted and the `\expandafter` is removed

   ```
   % next things TeX will look at
   \foo{<stuff>}
   ```

Now `\foo` can do its thing and all it does see is the expansion of `\stuff` (expanded just *once*, which is fine in your use case).

All this applied to your code to create new theorem environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{simple}%
    {}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {\normalfont}{}%
    {0pt}%
    {\thmname{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\thmnumber{ #2}\hspace{.4em}\textcolor{gray!55!paper}{$|$}\hspace{.4em}\color{gray}\thmnote{\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}~~}\pushQED{\qed}}
\def\@endtheorem{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\makebox[1em]{\color{gray!55!paper}\rule[-0.1em]{.95em}{.95em}}}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,linktoc=all}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nameinlink}{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3~\aftergroup\ignorespaces}

\theoremstyle{simple}

\newcommand\englishABBR{EN}
\newcommand\frenchABBR{FR}

%% macro for creating theorems
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\jinwen@createenvironment@starred[2]
  {%
    % #1: name
    % #2: star or empty
    \newtheorem*{#1EN#2}{\csname#1nameEN\endcsname}%
    \newtheorem*{#1FR#2}{\csname#1nameFR\endcsname}%
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1#2}{O{}}
      {\begin{#1\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#2}[{##1}]}
      {\end{#1\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#2}}%
  }
\newcommand\jinwen@createenvironment@nostar[4]
  {%
    % #1: name
    % #2: star or empty
    % #3: first optional argument to \newtheorem
    % #4: second optional argument to \newtheorem
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {%
        \IfNoValueTF{#4}
          {%
            \newtheorem{#1EN#2}{\csname #1nameEN\endcsname}%
            \newtheorem{#1FR#2}{\csname #1nameFR\endcsname}%
          }%
          {%
            \newtheorem{#1EN#2}{\csname #1nameEN\endcsname}[{#4}]%
            \newtheorem{#1FR#2}{\csname #1nameFR\endcsname}[{#4}]%
          }%
      }%
      {%
        \IfNoValueTF{#4}
          {%
            \newtheorem{#1EN#2}[{#3}]{\csname #1nameEN\endcsname}%
            \newtheorem{#1FR#2}[{#3}]{\csname #1nameFR\endcsname}%
          }%
          {%
            \PackageError{jinwen}
              {%
                You can't use both optional arguments,\MessageBreak
                they are mutually exclusive!\@gobble%
              }
              {}%
          }%
      }%
    \crefname{#1EN#2}
      {\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname #1nameEN\endcsname}}
      {\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname #1nameEN\endcsname}}%
    \crefname{#1FR#2}
      {\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname #1nameFR\endcsname}}
      {\protect\MakeUppercase{\csname #1nameFR\endcsname}}%
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1#2}{O{}}
      {\begin{#1\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#2}[{##1}]}
      {\end{#1\csname\languagename ABBR\endcsname#2}}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateTheorem}{smod<>}
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {% Stared version
        \IfEndWith{#2}{*}
          {% \CreateTheorem*{theorem*}
              \StrGobbleRight{#2}{1}[\temp]%
              \expandafter\jinwen@createenvironment@starred\expandafter{\temp}{*}%
          }
          {% \CreateTheorem*{theorem}
              \jinwen@createenvironment@starred{#2}{}%
          }%
      }
      {% Non-stared version
        \IfEndWith{#2}{*}
          {% \CreateTheorem{theorem*}[...]<...>
            \StrGobbleRight{#2}{1}[\temp]%
            \expandafter\jinwen@createenvironment@nostar\expandafter
              {\temp}{*}{#3}{#4}%
          }
          {% \CreateTheorem{theorem}[...]<...>
            \jinwen@createenvironment@nostar{#2}{}{#3}{#4}%
          }%
      }%
  }
\makeatother
\def\theoremnameEN{Theorem}
\def\theoremnameFR{Théorème}
\def\definitionnameEN{Definition}
\def\definitionnameFR{Définition}
\def\remarknameEN{Remark}
\def\remarknameFR{Remarque}
\def\notenameEN{Note}
\def\notenameFR{Note}

\newcounter{theorem}
\CreateTheorem{theorem}<section>
\CreateTheorem{definition}[theorem]
\CreateTheorem*{theorem*}
\CreateTheorem*{definition*}
\CreateTheorem*{remark}
\CreateTheorem{note*} % This is strange, only for test

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what do you want:

```
\createtheorem *{definition*}[theorem] ->          
    \newtheorem *{definitionEN*}[theorem]{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem *{definitionFR*}[theorem]{\definitionnameFR}    

\createtheorem *{definition}[theorem] ->          
    \newtheorem *{definitionEN}[theorem]{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem *{definitionFR}[theorem]{\definitionnameFR}

\createtheorem {definition}[theorem] ->          
    \newtheorem {definitionEN}[theorem]{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem {definitionFR}[theorem]{\definitionnameFR}

\createtheorem {definition} ->          
    \newtheorem {definitionEN}{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem {definitionFR}{\definitionnameFR}

\createtheorem*{definition} ->          
    \newtheorem*{definitionEN}{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem*{definitionFR}{\definitionnameFR}

\createtheorem*{definition*} ->          
    \newtheorem*{definitionEN*}{\definitionnameEN}
    \newtheorem*{definitionFR*}{\definitionnameFR}
```

I don't understand what these asterisks and paremeters in `[..]` exactly mean (because I don't use LaTeX), but it does not matter. If you want to do such macro `\createtheroem`, you can use this code:

```
\def\createtheorem#1#{\def\astA{#1}\createthmA}
\def\createthmA#1{\def\themname{#1}\futurelet\next\createthmB}
\def\createthmB{\ifx[\next\afterfi{\createthmC}\else\afterfi{\createthmC[]}\fi}
\def\createthmC[#1]{\def\astB{}\def\themopt{#1}%
   \expandafter\createthmD\themname*\end % \themname + *->\astB
   \createthmE{EN}\createthmE{FR}%
}
\def\createthmD#1*#2\end{\ifx^#2^\else\def\themname{#1}\def\astB{*}\fi}
\def\createthmE#1{%
    \edef\act{\noexpand\newtheorem\astA{\themname#1\astB}%
              \ifx\themopt\empty \else[\themopt]\fi
              {\expandafter\noexpand\csname\themname name#1\endcsname}}\act
}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
```