# Help understanding a macro using \GenericError with \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo

Tags: macros

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586269/194994), @UlrichDiez created a macro `\InnerCreateTheorem`, as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\InnerCreateTheorem}{mmmod<>}{%
   % #1 = star or no star
   % #2 = name of environment
   % #3 = emptiness or star to append to name of environment
   % #4 = numbered like
   % #5 = numbered within
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
     \IfValueTF{#4}{\@firstoftwo}{\IfValueTF{#5}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}}%
   }{\IfValueTF{#4}{\IfValueTF{#5}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}}{\@secondoftwo}}%
   {%
    \GenericError{}%
                 {\string\CreateTheorem\space syntax error\on@line}%
                 {You cannot call the starred variant with optional arguments.\MessageBreak
                  You cannot call the unstarred variant with several optional arguments.}%
                 {%
                   Allowed usage:\MessageBreak\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem*{(name of environment)}\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}[(numbered like)]\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}<(numbered within)>\MessageBreak
                   \CreateTheorem{(name of environment)}\MessageBreak
                   Captions come from macros \string\(name of environment)nameEN\MessageBreak
                   respective \string\(name of environment)nameFR.\MessageBreak
                   These macros must be defined separately.%
                 }%
   }{%
     %% ...
   }%
}%
```

However, I was confused about this. As I understood (according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do)), `\@firstoftwo` corresponds to `{\GenericError ...}` and `\@secondoftwo` corresponds to `{%%...}`. But `\GenericError` seems to have four cases, so under which circumstances would each one show up?

Comment: Your definition contains a superfluous "condition" for the first argument, since it's `m`andatory.

Comment: @Werner Sorry, I didn't understand your meaning. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: You test for `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` and state in the comments that argument `#1` is an optional star/not. However, that would require a parameter specification that resembles `smmod<>`, not `mmmod<>`.

Comment: @Werner Right, but this is because the `s` is processed in `\CreateTheorem`, which then calls the `\InnerCreateTheorem` above with `{*}` or `{}` (I didn't add the definition of `\CreateTheorem` here because it is irrelevant to this question). I doubt if this is the best way, but it certainly works.

Comment: @Werner Be aware that `\InnerCreateTheorem`'s test on `#1` is not `\IfValueTF` but is `\IfBooleanTF`. The first argument, `#1`, is passed in by another macro (`\CreateTheorem`) and holds tokens denoting the value of the boolean after evaluating that other macro's `s`-type-argument. So it denotes whether in the other macro (`\CreateTheorem`) a star was present or not. Thus that condition is not superfluous.

Comment: @Jinwen  The first argument of `\CreateTheorem` is `s`-type. This means: In case there is no star, `#1` of `\CreateTheorem` consists of tokens that denote the boolean-value "false". In case there is a star, `#1` of `\CreateTheorem` consists of tokens that denote the boolean-value "true". These tokens are passed on to `\InnerCreateTheorem` as it's 1st argument, an `m`-type-argument. So `\InnerCreateTheorem` can fork whether in `\CreateTheorem` a star was present by evaluating its 1st argument via `\IfBooleanTF`. (Not `\IfValueTF` which is used for testing `o`-type arguments, btw.)  This ...

Comment: @Jinwen ... This has nothing to do with `{*}`/`{}`. `{*}`/`{}` is passed as 3rd argument to `\InnerCreateTheorem` depending on whether the name of the environment to define ends with a star or not. `{*}`/`{}` is needed because you commented that you wish `fooEN*`, not `foo*EN`. In the hope that it clarifies things a bit I added some commenting about the meaning of arguments in my answer referred by you. I should have done this earlier, so I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenericError` does take four arguments, but they don't identify four different cases in which to issue an error. Instead the four argument represent (part of `ltxerror.dtx`; see the [LaTeX2e source documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/source2e)):

1. a continuation,
2. an error message,
3. where to go for further information, and
4. the help information.

So, with `\@firstoftwo`, you'll see an error generated by `\GenericError`.

Comment: What does "a continuation" mean? I looked at the documentation but it's not clear.

Comment: @PaulWintz: It's what is inserted as part of the line-break in the error message. So, if the error message is lengthy and has line breaks, you can insert "a continuation" - something at the start of each line that was broken. See [this code for `\PackageError`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV5eU.png) from the [LaTeX2e source](https://texdoc.net/pkg/source2e) - the first argument specifies `(ethel)` and some spaces as the "continuation" (the first argument of `\PackageError` is passed on as the first argument to `\GenericError`).